# Android: How to set position of MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want play video with aspect ratio in landscap mode.
so, I written following.

```
    landscape = true;
    // Get the dimensions of the video
    int videoWidth = mediaPlayer.getVideoWidth();
    int videoHeight = mediaPlayer.getVideoHeight();
    float videoProportion = (float) videoWidth / (float) videoHeight;

    // Get the width of the screen
    int screenWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    int screenHeight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    float screenProportion = (float) screenWidth / (float) screenHeight;

    // Get the SurfaceView layout parameters
    lp = surfaceView.getLayoutParams();
    lp.width = (int) (videoProportion * (float) screenHeight);
    lp.height = screenHeight;
   
    mVideoWidth = lp.width;
    mVideoHeight = lp.height;
    
    // Commit the layout parameters
    surfaceView.setLayoutParams(lp);
    holder.setFixedSize(mVideoWidth,  mVideoHeight); '
```

So, video play in landscape, but position is left.
I want that position is centre.
How implement?

Comment: Where is the xml layout for your activity?

Comment: Xml file is /res/layout-land folder.
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/videoSurfaceView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>